# The type or namespace name 'CrystalReportViewer' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, namespaces, report, 3-tier

I'm getting the following error on using crystal report in my asp.net 3.5 a3-tier application

> The type or namespace name 'CrystalReportViewer' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

the namespaces I have included are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using MorvelNew.Report;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to `Crystal.Web.dll` to the project?

Answer (score 10):

1. Right-click on "References" and select "Add Reference..."
2. Go to "Extensions"
3. Find "CrystalDecisions.Web"

and add namespace.

Answer (score 0):

missed few assemblies in web.config

```
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>

<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
<add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>
```